# Why in every real $C^1$ manifold can be endowed by an analytic structure

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I read  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8789/can-every-manifold-be-given-an-analytic-structure) the question if a smooth manifold can have analytic charts.

My question: Why  Whitney's embedding theorem allows to endow an analytic manifold structure  to a real $C^1$ manifold  ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you not also read the answers the question you linked? [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8789/can-every-manifold-be-given-an-analytic-structure/8794#8794) specifically answers your question.

Comment: The problem is that this answer does not provide a clear connection between the existence of an manifold embedding into the Euclidean space and the existence of analytic charts on the manifold.

Comment: Actually that answer is pretty clear, modulo some references. The answerer did not know to whom the "original credit" should go, but does provide a reference to a Millson-Kapovich paper. I've added the specific link to that answer.

Comment: On top of that, the answer goes on to give references to Nash's work. So, I'm sure you could find more details about this topic in some of these references.

Comment: Dear @Lee Mosher. I read the abstract of the reference that you edited in the answer: "Universality theorems for configuration spaces of planar linkages" . According to the abstract  is a statement about compact smooth manifolds.  So only  compact smooth manifolds have analytic charts?.